# How to show returned TypeScript data inside different borders in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have iterated JSON using .map() and returned data to HTML and applied CSS border to data.

**Expected Output:** Each data must have one separate border.

**Actual output:** All data have one border.

Here I'm returning 'Anitha' 'Saritha' to HTML, I want those names in two in different borders.

## test.ts

```
const obj = [{
    name: "Anitha",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    name: "Saritha",
    age: "29"
  },
]
this.name = obj.map(function(val) {
  return val.name
}).join('\n')
```

## test.html

```
<div id="borderDemo" style="white-space: pre-line">{{this.name}}</div>
```

## test.css

```
#borderDemo {
  border: 3px solid #1C6EA4;
}
```

Please suggest me the right approach  [Current output view attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsPxD.jpg)

Comment: two different border means , in same div or two different div

Answer (score 0):

The result is normal, as you write both names in the same HTML element `#borderDemo`.

If you are using Angular, I would suggest you to loop on you names inside your HTML.

test.ts

```
const obj = [
 { name: "Anitha", age: "25" },
 { name: "Saritha", age: "29" },    
];

this.names = obj;
```

test.html

```
<div id="borderDemo">
  <div *ngFor="let name of names" class="bordered">{{ name.name }}</div>
</div>
```

test.css

```
.bordered {
  border: 3px solid #1C6EA4;
}
```